# pgfplot - groupplot print x label only once in the last row

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, plot, groupplots

In the below group plot, the xvalues are common for all the subplots.
I want the x labels to be displayed only on the last row of the group plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 2},height=6cm,width=5cm,ybar,xtick=data,tick label style={font=\footnotesize},x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}
                                    ,symbolic x coords={metricA,metricB,metricC,metricD}]
    \nextgroupplot[title=A1,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a1a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a1b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A2,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a2a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a2b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A3,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a3a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a3b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A4,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a4a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a4b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

foo.csv

```
metric  a1a-value   a1b-value   a2a-value   a2b-value   a3a-value   a3b-value   a4a-value   a4b-value
metricA 20  30  50  55  55  20  30  50
metricB 40  40  60  23  23  40  40  60
metricC 50  20  70  67  67  50  20  70
metricD 60  50  20  20  20  60  50  20
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xticklabels at=edge bottom` as `group style` option.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group size= 2 by 2
        ,xticklabels at=edge bottom % <- added
    }
    ,height=6cm,width=5cm,ybar,xtick=data,tick label style={font=\footnotesize}
    ,x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}
    ,symbolic x coords={metricA,metricB,metricC,metricD}]
    \nextgroupplot[title=A1,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a1a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a1b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A2,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a2a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a2b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A3,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a3a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a3b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=A4,bar width=2pt]
        \addplot[fill=blue]     table[x=metric,y=a4a-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
        \addplot[fill=green]    table[x=metric,y=a4b-value,col sep=space]{foo.csv};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```